# Variables in another pp file cannot be fetched

Tags: puppet

I'm learning Puppet and start writing a module from this [tutorial](https://github.com/goofansu/puppet-openswan).

In `package.pp` and `config.pp`, I want to use `openswan::params::*nameOfVariable*`, but it remains `undef`.

I'm using version 3.1.1 of Puppet. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Haven't `include params` in `init.pp`.